# LOAD DATA INFILE ... SET column = NULLIF(column, 'NULL') gets incorrect value error

Tags: mariadb

On MariaDB-10.2.7, with a table schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE items (
  id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  deleted_at TIMESTAMP NULL
) ENGINE=innodb ;
```

The query:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '/items.csv'
INTO TABLE items
SET deleted_at = NULLIF(deleted_at, 'NULL') ;
```

items.csv (tab separated):

```
1 NULL
2 2019-07-24
```

The result:

```
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: 'NULL' for column 'deleted_at' at row 1
```

In the CSV, some of `deleted_at` are `NULL` as string (not `\N`). I'd like to convert it to NULL when running `LOAD DATA`.

Comment: What is the intent of that `SET`??

Comment: I've updated the description to make it clearer. My intention was converting `NULL` as string to [NULL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/null-values/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do it in 2 steps:

```
LOAD DATA ...
    (col1, col2, @deleted_at, col4)
    SET deleted_at = NULLIF(@deleted_at, 'NULL')
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SET sql_mode = '' ;
```

solved the error. MariaDB >=10.2.4 introduced `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` as default sql_mode and it makes `'NULL'` (string) as invalid for timestamp, so `deleted_at` will never be `'NULL'`.

`sql_mode = ''` does not raise the error, so `NULLIF(deleted_at, 'NULL')` works like `NULLIF('NULL', 'NULL')` in the first row of items.csv as I expected wrongly.

Comment: Note that `'NULL'` is a string; `NULL` is a "null".